# passing user defined parameters in WCF service causing problems

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am creating a wcf self hosted service. I am using UriTemplate class to customize the urls to methods.  the code snippet is given below

```
 public interface ISelfService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "ack/{errorcode}/{uniquefileid}")]
        [OperationContract]
        void Ack(ErrorCode errorcode, string uniquefileid);

       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "filechanged/{metainfo}")]
       [OperationContract]
       void FileChanged(MetaInformation metainfo);

     }
```

Whenever i run this program i am getting the following error

> Operation 'FileChanged' in contract 'ISelfHostService' has a query
>   variable named 'metainfo' of type 'Natash.Common.MetaInformation',
>   but type 'Natash.Common.MetaInformation' is not convertible by
>   'QueryStringConverter'. Variables for UriTemplate query values must
>   have types that can be converted by 'QueryStringConverter'

Can any one tell me why is this happening?

And, I have not made any modification to the web.config file. Do i need to make any modification there?

MetaInformation is defined as follows

```
[DataContract]
    public struct MetaInformation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string tags { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string categories { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I believe that your type is not convertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`public interface ISelfService{`

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/ack?errorcode={errorcode}&uniquefileid={uniquefileid}")]
    void Ack(ErrorCode errorcode, string uniquefileid);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/filechanged")]
    void FileChanged(MetaInformation metainfo);}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the message you posted it sounds like there are 2 definitions for the MetaInformation class (`Gettrix.Common.MetaInformation` & `Natash.Common.MetaInformation`).

It could be that both are in scope for WCF to see when instantiating the service.  If so, it might think that the one that does not have a DataContract attribute (probably `Natash.Common.MetaInformation`) is what you are reffering to and therefore would not be usable for data transfer within the service.

Comment: that was a typo. there is only one Namespace that is Natash.Common.MetaInformation. thanks for pointing that out. edited the question.

Comment: I just realized what the problem is, you cannot use anything other than a primitive type in the url.  To pass a complex type, it has to be included in the body of the REST call.  You would need to change the url signature to "filechanged/".  WCF will pull the data from the body (as either JSON or XML as you specify) and instantiate the MetaInformation class for you.